# CMV Layers widget loads only intermittently

Tags: configurable-map-viewer

Without any code changes, the contents of the Layers widget, my layer tree hierarchy, loads sometimes, and other times does not load.

It usually works on the first load of the page, then may fail to load on refreshes.  Clearing the cache seems like it helps sometimes.

The behavior is so inconsistent, it is really difficult to diagnose.

It is an internal application, so I can't share.

Has this ever been encountered before?

Comment: @tmcgee Perhaps you have encountered this behavior before?  I put the application on a different server, but the result is the same, so I am assuming the problem is in the code.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the older version was likely to blame for this and I upgraded the CMV application to v2.0.0 beta 2.  That fixed it!